# Error when friending a function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to work around the limitation that the default ctor of a custom Qt meta type has to be public by declaring certain functions as friends.

```
#include <QMetaType>

class QVariant;
template<typename T> inline T qvariant_cast(const QVariant &); // from qvariant.h

namespace foo
{
  class Bar
  {
  private:
    Bar(){};
    friend void *::qMetaTypeConstructHelper<Bar>(const Bar *t); // works
    friend inline Bar ::qvariant_cast<Bar>(const ::QVariant &v); // error C4430: missing type specifier
  };
} // namespace foo

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(foo::Bar)

void main()
{
  QVariant v;
  v.value<foo::Bar>();
}
```

When commenting out the marked line, I get the following error, which is expected:

```
1>[...]\qvariant.h(577): error C2248: 'foo::Bar::Bar' : cannot access private member declared in class 'foo::Bar'
```

But declaring the function as a friend doesn't work:

```
Bar.cpp(13): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

It almost seems like MSVC 2010 doesn't see the space between the "Bar" and the "::".

Aside from making the default ctor public, how can I get it to compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It almost seems like MSVC 2010 doesn't see the space between the "Bar" and the "::".

Spaces don't matter around `::` meaning `foo::bar` is the same as `foo ::bar`.

Try adding parenthesis around the function name:

```
friend inline Bar (::qvariant_cast<Bar>)(const ::QVariant &v);
```

Comment: Ah, ok. So this has nothing to do with templates. Thanks.